# Tomcat on EC2 lost cookie

Tags: tomcat, cookies, ssh, amazon-ec2, single-sign-on

I have a project deployed in my local tomcat and SSO has been configured in the project. When I start the project in tomcat. It works correctly and I can view the cookies of SSO in browser.

However, when I deploy the project on the tomcat which is on EC2, the tomcat is run and I connect the tomcat server by ssh tunnel. Then when I pass SSO validation, I find the cookie is missing.

Is there any one meet the problem before? Can you give me any idea to solve the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Research the problem again:

Tomcat 7.0.26 will have the problem "SSO-cookie is not generated" in my local box. On the other hand, Tomcat 7.0.42 doesn't have the problem.

Is there any one know the cause?

Comment: The problem is fixed since I found my configuration files have something wrong

Comment: I am facing same issue can you please provide more detail about the causes of issue. Thanks